# Getting Sorting Order of Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I want to save the sorting order of the table and when refreshed it should sort on the saved status.

I am using the **Tablesorter jquery plugin**  for sorting of table

I used javascript to store them in the localstorage but it is storing entire table

javascript Code :

```
  $("#videoTable").on("sortEnd", function SaveSortOrder() {
        var table_layout = $('#videoTable')[0].innerHTML;
        localStorage.setItem("tableLayout",table_layout);
    });
```

HTML Code:

```
 <table class="table sortable" id="videoTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr valign="middle">
                        <th data-sort="name" class="tooltipPoint col-lg-4" style="text-align:left;">Name <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></th> 
                        <th data-sort="name" class="tooltipPoint text-center" nowrap>Status <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
                        <th class="unclickable text-center">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                       The body will be generated dynamically.
                </tbody>
 </table>
```

Is there any way to retrieve only the headers or only the column (Index of the column in a table) we are sorting so that I can modify the class based on the result.

Sorry for bad English. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the HTML part.

Comment: *"...but it is storing entire table..."* Well....yes. That's what you're explicitly telling it to do. Did you check the TableSorter documentation? What did you find?

Comment: @RaxWeber: Hard to see why that's relevant here.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was just trying to see what the `innerHTML` value would be just to make sure that nothing's wrong with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort column. Save only what column how sorted (dont know how to get current sort from tablesorter)
2. On page load check if any sort is saved in local storage.
3. If so, apply it with sortList.

You should consider new data may be added. Thats why your solution is not right.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if you want to add a class to the column that was sorted you could manage that at the table header level, something along the lines of this:

```
jQuery("#videoTable th.tooltipPoint").on("click",function(){
    jQuery("#videoTable th.tooltipPoint").removeClass("sorted");
    jQuery(this).addClass("sorted");
});
```